# Cannot make a Generic Class of Type System.Fabric.FabricServiceNotFoundException when using c# reflection

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, reflection, azure-service-fabric

I have the following function that takes in an error and creates a class instance of `ErrorType<T>`

```
 private dynamic GenerateDynamicErrorHandler(Exception ex)
    {
        try
        {
            string typeName = ex.GetType().FullName;
            Type typeArgument = Type.GetType(typeName);
            Type genericClass = typeof(ErrorType<>);

            Type constructedClass = genericClass.MakeGenericType(typeArgument);

            dynamic created = Activator.CreateInstance(constructedClass);
            return created;
        }
        catch
        {
            throw new ReflectionException(ex.GetType().FullName);
        }
    }
```

Which then returns a `dynamic` object in the following code snippet:

```
 try
        {
            dynamic c = GenerateDynamicErrorHandler(ex);

            if (c.IsError())
            {
                return c.GenericResponse<ErrorDetails,AppendingErrors>(isDebug,
                    isDefaultConverter,
                    context, 
                    _errorDetailResponseFactory.CreateDefaultError(ex.Message,ex.InnerException,context.Response.StatusCode),
                    new AppendingErrors
                    {
                        Title = c.Get().Title,
                        ResultCode = c.Get().ResultCode,
                        StackTrace = ex.StackTrace

                    });
            }
            return HandleError.WithDefaultJsonConverter<ErrorDetails>(context, 
                _errorDetailResponseFactory.CreateDefaultError(ex.Message,ex.InnerException,context.Response.StatusCode));
        }
        catch(ReflectionException re)
        {
            return HandleError.WithGenericApendingJsonConverter<ErrorDetails, object>(context,
            _errorDetailResponseFactory.CreateDefaultError(ex.Message, ex.InnerException, context.Response.StatusCode), 
            new {
                reflectionError = re.Message
            });
        }
```

This works for all Exceptions except for `System.Fabric.FabricServiceNotFoundException` and I dont understand or have any clue as to why. If anyone could assist with this, it would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Why do you get the type name from the Type and then the Type from the type name.  The `ex.GetType()` call gives you the type, just use it

Comment: @Flydog57 Thats a valid point. I forgot to mention that the code breaks on the Line  `Type constructedClass = genericClass.MakeGenericType(typeArgument);`

Comment: @Flydog57 Thank you for that simple solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So thanks to @Flydog57 the problem was actually getting the name of the type and then trying to make a type from that name. The simple fix was to, as said in the comment, just use the type of the exception passed in

```
private dynamic GenerateDynamicErrorHandler(Exception ex)
    {
        try
        {
            Type typeArgument = ex.GetType();
            Type genericClass = typeof(ErrorType<>);

            Type constructedClass = genericClass.MakeGenericType(typeArgument);

            dynamic created = Activator.CreateInstance(constructedClass);
            return created;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            throw new ReflectionException(ex.GetType().FullName);
        }
    }
```